# Java Rest Service Print a List with Newline

Tags: java, string, list, rest, arraylist

I have a rest service that I want to access and have print out each element of a list on a new line in the browser. Here's that code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAlerts(@RequestParam(value="code") String code) {
    StringBuilder sBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    for(Identity identity : service.getIdentityList(code)) {
        sBuffer.append(identity.toString());
        sBuffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    return sBuffer.toString();
}
```

The service works any everything and the list gets printed but as 1 line. I want it to get printed on a separate line. How do I do that? I don't think sBuffer is the way to go...I've even tried:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAlerts(@RequestParam(value="code") String code) {
    List<Identity> identityList = service.getIdentityList(code);
    return identityList.toString();
}
```

But it's still printing out as 1 line in the browser....any ideas on how to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the browser you need to use `<br>` for a line break.

Comment: yep, i'm an idiot. No idea why that slipped by me. Thanks

Comment: Another pair of eyes is always helpful ;)